# Running sql script from Windows Forms Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, smo

I am building a VB.NET desktop application in VS2013 that uses a .mdf file created in SQL Server 2012. I have the .mdf file imported in to the application. Along with the datagridviews I am using to view/modify the database tables I need to execute a SQL script when the user clicks on a button.

I have been trying several examples I've found, without any luck. I'm getting a FileLoadException error on the ExecuteNonQuery line:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version
>   'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime
>   without additional configuration information.

The "Troubleshooting tips" section has "Make sure that the file is a valid .NET Framework assembly". I clicked on that link, but the information there isn't very helpful to me, as I really am not understanding what it's saying.

I've tried these two examples so far:

```
Dim sqlScript As String = "C:\HL_Time_Entry_Reporting\SQL Scripts\stage_employee_hours_load.sql"
Dim connString As String = "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\HL_Time_Entry_Reporting\Database\hours_analysis.mdf"
Dim connectionString As String = connString,
    scriptText As String = sqlScript
Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim svrConnection As New ServerConnection(sqlConnection)
Dim server As New Server(svrConnection)
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptText)
```

from [this site](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/c-executing-batch-t-sql-scripts-with-go-statements/). And

```
Dim sqlConnectionString As String = "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\HL_Time_Entry_Reporting\Database\hours_analysis.mdf"
Dim file As New FileInfo("C:\HL_Time_Entry_Reporting\SQL Scripts\stage_employee_hours_load.sql")
Dim script As String = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd()
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)
Dim server As New Server(New ServerConnection(conn))
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script)
```

from [this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4419/executing-sql-file-form-C-Sharp.aspx).

One thing is, I'm not confident I have the correct connection string for this. That's the connection string I have for the datagridviews, which works fine, but is that also what I should use to connect for the sql script file as well?

**UPDATE**

Per request, here is the stack trace:

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetStatements(String
>   query, ExecutionTypes executionType, Int32& statementsToReverse)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand)    at test.main.btnLoadMasterData_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Users\marky\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Hours Analysis\Hours Analysis\Form1.vb:line 212    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at test.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in
>   17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

**UPDATE #2**

As suggested, I added the startup tag in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286000/run-sql-file-from-application-in-c-sharp-using-smo-library/11286124#11286124) to my appconfig file but got a new error on the line "Dim server As New Server(New ServerConnection(conn))" in the second code example. It's a TypeInitializationException. Here's the info:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.

Stack trace:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
>   SqlCredential credential)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>   at test.main.btnLoadMasterData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\marky\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hours
>   Analysis\Hours Analysis\Form1.vb:line 210    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at test.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in
>   17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I don't think that this is specifically a SQL Server problem, nor a problem with your .mdf, but rather a .Net Framework problem of some kind.  Can you post the entire stack trace from the exception?

Comment: My suspicion though is that you using an out of date SMO assembly, or a user class library assembly built under a different .Net Framework version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be using an obsolete version of the SMO library, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286124/109122.

### Update:

If the config setting recommended at the link does not work, try this simpler one instead:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

---

Unfortunately, it appears that the config file changes do not fix all cases.

Comment: Please see my Update #2.